# Trying to setup Linux Service in IBM Tivoli Identity Manager (ITIM)

Tags: linux, ssh, tivoli-identity-manager

I am currently trying to setup a Linux service with IBM Tivoli Identity Manager (IBM Security Identity Manager) a.k.a. ITIM, to a Linux development server where I work and have had some issues. All our Linux servers use ssh to connect. Our eventual goal is to implement single sign on across our networks using Identity Manager.

In the ITIM web interface, I chose the option MANAGE SERVICES and was displayed a page like the following, where I click the CREATE button to create a new service:

[image: Manage Services]

Then I am next shown a page where I choose the kind of service I want to make, in this page I choose the POSIX LINUX option because I want to connect to a Linux Server.

[image: Choose Service Type]

Then on the next page, I am entering the information for my Linux server that I want to connect to, the domain name for the server is phongdev.fit.edu, a server for development work.

[image: Enter Server Information]

Note on this page there is a field titled TIVOLI DIRECTORY INTEGRATOR (TDI) where there is default information for the TDI installation, in my case, TDI is installed on the same server as ITIM is installed, so the localhost domain name should be fine. However when I check the server using netstat command there is nothing running on that port, 16231, so I looked up the instructions for starting the TDIDispatcher on google and was told to run the following command, /etc/init.d/ITIMAd restart at the command line and that appeared to run successfully, however still nothing running on port 16231 on the server.

Since our servers use SSH I was required by ITIM to setup key based authentication, I did setup a key and passphrase on this Linux server using ssh, and entered the data on the next screen of ITIM which looks like the following, but as you can see an error is generated when I choose the TEST CONNECTION button:

[image]

I checked the logs and there is no info in the logs for these errors, I am not sure where to move next in trying to solve this issue, i suspect it may be related to the fact that the TDI Dispatcher does not appear to be running on port 16231.

Answer (score 0):

TDI is probably running on a different port.  You didn't specify if TDI is running on Windows or Linux, so my answer is assumes Linux since that is what I am most familiar with.

You can find your port # by looking in the solution.properties file in your TDI/timsol directory.  It should be listed as `api.remote.naming.port`.

TDI runs on the default port 1099.  Once you start TDI (service ITIMAd start, or however you start it on your system) use `ps auxw | grep -i rmi` (or something similar) to find the process.  Then use `netstat -anp | grep PID` where PID is the process ID of the TDI RMI process.  You should see immediately what port it is listening on.  I am not where I have access to a TDI server right now to get you exact commands, but you should get the idea.

Here is a good article for ISIM 6 (should be the same for ITIM 5.1 on TDI 7) on changing the port # for the RMI:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v2r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.itim_pim.doc%2Fdispatcher%2Finstall_config%2Ft_changeportnum.htm

If you are experiencing error CTGIMT600E and you have multiple network interfaces on TDI 6 or lower, you may need to specify your server IP (or hostname) as a java property so the TDI RMI binds on the correct interface.  Edit `<tdi_home>/ibmdisrv` and insert `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<yourhost>`.  For more infomration refer to this article:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21381101

If you are still having issues, watch your ITIM msg.log and trace.log when you test the connection and look for clues.  Also look at the TDI ibmdi.log which will be located under your TDI directory.  That may also help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am running TDI and ITIM on Red Hat Linux and from your directions it appears the TDI is running on port 1099, now I get an CTGIMT600E An error occurred while establishing communication with the Tivoli Directory Integrator server. Error: ITDIDispatcher, I think it is still within 1 year since my employer purchased this IBM software, so I can open a free support ticket with IBM.

Comment: I was looking through the solution.properties file and noticed that these two lines are commented out: com.ibm.di.default.bind.address=*
api.remote.bind.address=* and also further down in the properties file these two properties are set to FALSE, api.jmx.on=false
api.jmx.remote.on=false, is it possible that these are the source of the error?

Comment: Sees you must have a newer TDI version. Those properties commented out will equate to the default of bind to all interfaces. See this page for more info: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v2r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.IBMDI.doc_7.1%2Fadminguide38.htm  I added some more details regarding old versions of TDI and also where to look for the logs.  If you have support, definitely open a PMR, as IBM ITIM/ISIM support is great.

Comment: It looks like the Dispatcher is not installed on the Linux server, on the IBM website it says to verify that certain files are on the server and most of those files are not present on my server, I am having a Sys Admin look at installing the Dispatcher software for me, it kind of makes sense that it is not installed since it is not installed by default with Directory Integrator, according to the IBM website it has to be installed separately.

Comment: You should see a java process running with IDILoader.jar with the config file ITIM_RMI.xml specified (use `ps auxw | grep RMI.xml`) if you have the RMI running.  Otherwise yes grab a copy from IBM's site (or your ITIM/ISIM CD).  It is a very simple install.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what Matt said (the link especially is useful), the var/ibm/tivoli/common/TDI logs should tell you what the problem with TDI is when you start it up - if there's a problem.
The port number where it's listening ought to be mentioned somewhere in those logs.
Unless there was an upgrade or multiple attempts to configure the RMI dispatcher I don't see why the port shouldn't be 16231 or 1099.